# How to pass facebook access token via AFNetworking

Tags: ios, http, facebook-graph-api, afnetworking

I am trying to make a GET request with AFNetworking to facebook's graph api. For various reasons, I'd rather not use the facebook SDK's native objects and would prefer to make those requests via AFNetworking. However, I'm a bit new to the networking side of things and I am unsure how to include the access token along with my GET request. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've tried setting the http header field to include this:

Authentication : {my access token}

but that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `access_token` as a URL query parameter for GET requests. See the docs [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/#access_tokens).